# Issues with date output with DropDate add-on

Tags: add-on, date, dropdate, title-master

I'm using Stephen Lewis' now unsupported DropDate add-on to simplify selecting dates in the Control Panel. (Chiefly because I'm trying to use a fieldtype that allows me to disable selecting times. I want my Control Panel users to just pick a date. If there are other options to do this that I haven't seen, I'm open to them.) I'm using EE 2.5.5.

I first noticed that the dates were outputting one day behind when just choosing a date. So if I selected & saved May 1 2013 in the entry, the output from the tag would be April 30 2013. (I'm also using Title Master to put the date into the entry's title using the DropDate fieldtype tag, and the same thing was happening there.)

I assumed that this was because the date saved was UTC and my server is 5 hours or more behind. I could, however, find no way to compensate for that.

After poking around on Devot:ee and in the readme files with the add-on, I found the git repository and the recommendation to use the re-written [Dev branch](https://github.com/experience/dropdate.ee_addon/tree/develop).

I've given this a try, and can report that in my local, Mac/MAMP Pro environment things look right. Why they look right, I don't know. In my template I have:

```
{wedding-date-date format="l, F d, Y"}
```

And it just works. I should point out that, for another project, my php.ini file has:

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

in it.

The same tag is storing the correct value in Title Master. (When I configured Title Master to include `{wedding-date-date format="F d, Y" timezone="Greenwich"}`, it didn't have any impact or output the date differently.

**On my server, however**, I'm continually seeing this error when Title Master updates the entry title:

```
An invalid timezone parameter was passed to DropDate.
```

That's the tag output there, being bundled into the entry title.

I've updated `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` on my server (Ubuntu) to have:

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

in it and reloaded/restarted Apache. I'm still seeing the same thing, including in template output. The output of the tag is simply:

```
An invalid timezone parameter was passed to DropDate.
```

Whether or not I include the parameter.

Has anyone run into this and gotten it working? I really need two things to work here:

1. Admins able to just choose a date in the entry.
2. Title Master to be able to insert that date field's formatted value into the entry title.

**Update** I've downgraded MAMP Pro from PHP 5.4.4 to 5.3.14, using the default template which has `date.timezone = MAMP_timezone_MAMP` & things worked fine locally. Going down to 5.2.17, less than the server's 5.2.4, broke things locally. Think I might see the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Built a new server for the client and deployed there, with a newer version of PHP. Error has gone away.